# JTextField won't disappear completely

Tags: java, jtextfield, dialog

I created a dialog box and have the user enter 5 colors in it from memory. That all completely works, there's just a slight aesthetic problem. Upon entering all 5 colors correctly, or getting one incorrect, it's suppose to wipe the contents within the dialog box and print a message "Sorry! Incorrect color" or "Congratulations". It prints the message, but the JTextField can still be seen somewhat behind the message (A left over portion/clipping).

I've tried using the hide() and remove() methods but they didn't seem to work (Or I'm using them incorrectly), I tried re-making a dialog box upon either but I couldn't seem to solve the issue still. What am I doing wrong/how can I make the JTextField disappear upon completion? Thank you in advance for any help!

Here's the portion where if the user enters a color incorrectly or gets them all correct (txtName is the JTextField):

```
        if(count == 6)//User either finished or entered a color incorrectly
        {                
            //Entered color incorrectly
            if(incorrect == true)
            {                    
                txtName.setEnabled(false); //Doesn't work
                homeScreen.remove(txtName); //Doesn't work
                labelName.setText("Incorrect! Sorry - Wrong color.");
                //txtName.removeActionListener(new MyButtonListener());
            }
            else//Correctly finished the game.
            {
                labelName.setText("Congratulations - your memory skills are perfect!");
                //txtName.removeActionListener(new MyButtonListener());
                homeScreen.remove(txtName);//Doesn't work
            }
        }
```

Here's my entire program (I can't get it format properly in the post):

```
package memorygame;

import java.util.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class MemoryGame 
{
    private JFrame homeScreen;
    private JLabel labelName;
    private JTextField txtName;
    private JLabel correct;
    Vector<String> name = new Vector();
    private int count = 1;

    private MyButtonListener listen1 = new MyButtonListener();

    //Constructor - Method to be called when MemoryGame object called
    public void MemoryGame ()
    {
        homeScreen = new JFrame();    
        homeScreen.setSize(400,200);
        homeScreen.setTitle("Memory Game");  
        homeScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(homeScreen.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        homeScreen.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
        labelName = new JLabel();
        txtName = new JTextField(10);
        createContents();
        homeScreen.setVisible(true);
    }//End Constructor

    //Create components and add them to the window/dialog box
    private void createContents()
    {       
        labelName.setText("Enter the color " + count + ":");
        System.out.println("The current count is: " + count);
        homeScreen.add(labelName); 
        homeScreen.add(txtName);
        txtName.addActionListener(new MyButtonListener());//Allows you to press enter to invoke action
    }
    //Upon user hitting enter
    private class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)//When event occurs
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);//For program input
            String answer = "";
            //Make memColor an array for randomized colors
            /*

            Random r = new Random();
            String[] memColors = new String[5];             
            String[] colors = {"red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "brown", "purple"};

            for(int i =0; i < memColors.length; i++)
            {
                memColors[i] = colors[r.nextInt(6)];
            }
            */
            String memColor1 = "red";
            String memColor2 = "black";
            String memColor3 = "yellow";
            String memColor4 = "green";
            String memColor5 = "blue";
            boolean incorrect = false;

            //If answered incorrectly set count to 5(it'll be 6)
            //And have a boolean for if count== 6 for congrats and failure
            if(e.getSource() == txtName)
            {
                answer = txtName.getText();
                System.out.println(answer);
            }
            else
            {}     
            //Check if user entered Correct color, 1= Red, 2= Black, etc.
            if(count == 1)
            {
                if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(memColor1))
                {
                    txtName.setText("");                
                }
                else
                {//Needs to be a custom message box
                    count = 5;
                    incorrect = true;
                }                
             }
            else if(count == 2)
            {
                if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(memColor2))
                {
                    txtName.setText("");       
                }
                else
                {                  
                    count = 5;
                    incorrect = true;
                }                
            }            
            else if(count == 3)
            {
                if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(memColor3))
                {
                    txtName.setText("");                
                }
                else
                { 
                    count = 5;
                    incorrect = true;
                } 
            }
            else if(count == 4)
            {
                if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(memColor4))
                {
                    txtName.setText("");                
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 5;
                    incorrect = true;
                }
            }
            else if(count == 5)
            {
                if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(memColor5))
                {
                    txtName.setText("");

                }
                else
                {
                    count = 5;
                    incorrect = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong!");
            }            

            count += 1;
            //User has completed the game or entered a color incorrectly
            if(count == 6)
            {

                if(incorrect == true) //Incorrect color
                {                    
                    txtName.setEnabled(false);
                    homeScreen.remove(txtName);
                    labelName.setText("Incorrect! Sorry - Wrong color.");
                    //txtName.removeActionListener(new MyButtonListener());
                }
                else //Completed the game correctly
                {
                    labelName.setText("Congratulations - your memory skills are perfect!");
                    //txtName.removeActionListener(new MyButtonListener());
                    homeScreen.remove(txtName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                labelName.setText("Enter the color " + count + ":");
            }              
        }//End Listener        
    }//End Button class

        public static void main(String[] args) {       

        //Show message box
        //Randomize colors
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "How good is your memory?\nTry to memorize this color sequence:\n\n red black yellow green blue");

        MemoryGame mem = new MemoryGame();        
        mem.MemoryGame();        
    }//End Main
}// End Class
```

Comment: Try using `txtName.setVisible(false);` instead of `homeScreen.remove(txtName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `txtName.setVisible(false);` instead of `homeScreen.remove(txtName);`

Basically, if you want to call `remove`, you will need to `revalidate` and `repaint` container...

You'll also want to ensure that your UI is create within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I don't understand what the context of an Event Dispatching Thread is, but I will look into it more from that link.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code

```
homeScreen.remove(txtName);
```

to

```
homeScreen.remove(txtName);
homeScreen.revalidate();
homeScreen.repaint();
```

The reason why `remove()` does not imply `revalidate()` + `repaint()` is that `remove()` is not atomic. The caller might want to perform multiple updates, a sequence of several `add()` and `remove()` calls. `revalidate()` basically "completes" your "UI update transaction", `repaint()` "pushes it to the screen".

As a side note, your code will be easier to understand and maintain, if you perform a small tiny improvements on variable names. What's `homeScreen`? And why is it called `labelName` - what name? And what's `txtName` - the name of what text? `count` of what, icecreams?

I suggest the following improvements:

- `incorrect` -> `isIncorrect` (also change `if (incorrect == true)` to `if (isIncorrect)`
- `homeScreen` -> `mainFrame` or just `frame` (as you only have one frame)
- `labelName` -> `infoLabel` or just `label` (as you only have one label - and remove `JLabel correct`, it's unused)
- `txtName` -> `answerTextField`
- `count` -> `answerCount`

Remove variable `listen1`, it's not used.

Plus, if you look at the code that does `if (count == 1)` and the following four `if` clauses, they are all identical except for the number. A perfect situation for an array. You can convert the variables `memColor*` to an array `String[] memColor`. Or maybe that's what the Vector was for. You might instead want to use `ArrayList`, nobody uses `Vector` these days in such situations.

Comment: Thank you very much for going through my entire code and pointing out what I could improve and explaining the revalidate and repaint methods! I'm currently fixing my code with those updates. I had planned to make memColor an array, but I did not think of doing the if statements as an array. Thanks!